# How to create Django like button for anonymous users?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-sessions

I am using Django and my website has no user profiles so all are anonymous. I want to implement a 'like' system. How do I restrict a user to like only once. Thanks.

Comment: [Django-Secretballot](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot)  is an awesome app which does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any way of identifying your users then your best bet is to store this info in a **browser cookie** or **HTML5 local storage**. (I don't advise using flash cookies since there is a long debate about them and they are harder to implement)

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* 100% restrict multiple votes, but you can make it very difficult for a regular user, by using:

- a cookie
- a DB entry with the voter's IP

Answer (score 0):

Facebook seems to track uniqueness of likes when its tied to a facebook app though the XFBML script.  Regardless of whether I'm logged in or logged out of facebook, the like button seems to recognize that I've already voted.

- Creating a facebook app can currently be done here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- An interesting feature of facebooks apps is facebook `insights`, which can be found here: http://www.facebook.com/insights/
- Supporting documentation for facebook insights can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

While still in its infancy, there is a project called `django-like-button` which provides a wrapper for facebooks XFBML like button. If you're using pip and virtualenv, you can `pip install django-like-button` and follow the readme.rst installation instructions.  The project can be found on github.