# Django like button for unregistered user

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am trying to create a like button for post. How to allow unregistered user to like the post and how to identify the user for uniqueness. Should I use cookies or ip address.

Comment: For example many WordPress website has like button for visitors.

Comment: Share your logic/code in `views.py`?

Comment: how do you defined `unregistered user` ? by field ? share your user models.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006882/how-to-create-django-like-button-for-anonymous-users

Comment: How to do using ip address